# gc_thresh kernel config issues

Tags: linux, kernel, arp

We were having problems with kernel logs in our datacenter:

```
arp_cache: neighbor table overflow!
```

It was related to all of our servers having consul on them using gossip protocol and "flooding" the arp cache. I use flooding loosely because there are 300ish members, but that is way below the default gc_thresh3 limit and we only saw 25 of them in there at any given time. We doubled all the settings below across all servers:

> gc_thresh1 (since Linux 2.2)
>   The minimum number of entries to keep in the ARP cache. The garbage collector will not run if there are fewer than this number of entries in the cache. Defaults to 128.
>
> gc_thresh2 (since Linux 2.2)
>   The soft maximum number of entries to keep in the ARP cache. The garbage collector will allow the number of entries to exceed this for 5 seconds before collection will be performed. Defaults to 512.
>
> gc_thresh3 (since Linux 2.2)
>   The hard maximum number of entries to keep in the ARP cache. The garbage collector will always run if there are more than this number of entries in the cache. Defaults to 1024.

This fixed the issue, but I don't know why because when I arp -n it's nowhere near the 1024 entries it would have taken to hit the gc_thresh3. I looked through the code in our kernel version:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/31cc088a4f5d83481c6f5041bd6eb06115b974af/net/core/neighbour.c#L388

And it seems like a simple increment, which aligns with the documentation, but it evicts way before the limits and throws that error message above. Does anyone have insight into what I'm not understanding or how my analysis is wrong? I want to figure this out so we can plan for what to appropriately set these settings to. Thanks in advance!